# Hiding a bootstrap modal with jquery under a certain condition

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to modify a modal that opens on click within a user account and blocks access to certain features on the website. Once the user obtains premium access to the account, I'd like this modal to disappear. I'm very new to jQuery.

The script for modal is below

```
 $(document).on('click', '[data-activebs-message]', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.userprofile__activebs_modal').modal().addClass('open');
    });

    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.userprofile__activebs_modal', function () {
        $('.userprofile__activebs_modal').removeClass('open');
    });

    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#show_modal', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().html('');
    });
```

It's activated in the html with this:

```
 {% if profile is not null and profile.active == true %}

            <div class="modal fade userprofile__activebs_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="show_modal_label"
                 aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                       <button type="button" class="close no-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            </button>
            <div class="modal-title">
                <h4 class="text-center"> {{ 'inactive_box.paragraph_3' | trans({}, 'user_profile') }} </h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <a class="link link--yellow link--underline2 mr-5" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                 <i class="fa-light fa-circle-x"></i> {{ 'buttons.no' | trans({},'forms') | raw | upper }}

                </a>
                <a class="link link--underline2 link--red2" href="{{ path('user_profile_third_step_premium',{
                                    'profileId':[profile.id.toString]
                                }) }}">
                 <i class="fa-light fa-circle-check"></i>  {{ 'buttons.yes' | trans({},'forms') | raw | upper }}

                </a>


                        <div class="modal-footer">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
```

I need for that userprofile__activebs_modal to be destroyed or for that function to be disabled when I have a new condition in the html:

{% if **profile.premiumActive** == true %}

Don't know how to modify the modal script

Comment: You can add the language in your code to activate syntax highlighting using the markdown https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: About your question, the javascript and django part do not run at same time. 
Your script python will run first and create the html and js part, then they will send it to the browser and run. The js part can't be destroyed by the python after the page is rendered. You will need some ajax call to the backend in order to know when destroy your modal and remove it using javascript also.